# Check for one value in column A exist in another column B in open office

Tags: openoffice

suppose I have values like

```
A   B    C
abc cde
bcd abc
cde afg
mn   mn
```

for column C I have used formula =IF(MATCH(A1;B2:B4;0);A1)

But its **giving wrong ouput** like below

```
A   B   C
abc cde  #N/A
bcd abc  #N/A
cde afg  #N/A
mn    mn    mn
```

since abc and cde in column A exist in column B **output should be something like this**:

```
A   B   C
abc cde  abc
bcd abc  #N/A
cde afg  cde
mn    mn    mn
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this formula:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2;$B$2:$B$718;1;0));A2;"")
```

output is

```
 A   B   C
abc cde  
bcd abc  bcd
cde afg  
mn   mn
```

Answer (score 3):

I have tried your (modified) formula. It works fine!

```
=IF(MATCH(A1;B$1:B$4;0);A1)
```

Result:

[image]

If you get #N/A errors, then it could be that the data in column A and column B are not exactly the same (hidden spaces). You could use =trim(A1) in C1 and =trim(B1) in D1 and copy it down, then run your formula in column E.

Comment: @Mohini, Please provide feedback on the proposed solutions. When an answer was helpful, please "Accept" that answer by clicking on the WHITE "Check-mark" next to the answer, to turn it GREEN. Thank you! Clicking the check-mark will give credits to the person who submitted the answer and will mark the question as answered. See: [Accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/210367)

Comment: Yeah I didn't put that $ symbol. +1 From me-:)

Answer (score 1):

Use the VLOOKUP call instead.  In C2:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2;B2:B4,1)
```

This means find A1 in range B2:B4 and return the first column with an exact match.